# How to run a python file from another python file with parameters?

Tags: python, file, module

I tried a couple of methods for running a python file from another but none of them worked with parameters (with subprocess I used pyinstaller to convert the py to exe):

```
import subprocess
import os
subprocess.run(program_of_choice, shell=True)
subprocess.call(program_of_choice)
os.system(py_file)
```

Can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
file_to_run = "" #add target path
command = ""   #add your python directory (eg: C:\\python37\\python.exe)
parameters = "" #add params
os.command(command+file_to_run+parameters)
```

You can arrange the parameters, file_to_run etc based on your usage of it.